# Let X, Y be i.i.d, X+Y and X-Y independent, show that the characteristic function E{exp(i<2u,x>)}= ...

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. Suppose further that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent. Show that $\varphi_{X}(2u)=(\varphi_{X}(u))^{3}\varphi_{X}(-u)$.

What I tried to do was work backwards, starting with the right side: $(\varphi_{X}(u))^{3}\varphi_{X}(-u)=(\varphi_{X})^{3}\overline{\varphi_{X}(u)} = E\{exp(i\langle u, X \rangle)\}^{3} E\{exp(-i\langle u, X\rangle)\}$. Then, by independence, $= \left[\prod_{j=1}^{n}\varphi_{x _{j}}(u_{j})\right]^{3}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\varphi_{x_{j}}(-u_{j})$.

I'm really not sure if I'm approaching this right, or how I'm going to get the two sides to equal each other. I'm a little lost, so I would REALLY appreciate help on this one! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Where does $Y$ enter in what you are asking? (meant as a hint, not as a clarification)

Comment: I've been trying to figure that out myself, and I'm wondering if it was a typo in the textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $Z = X+Y$ and $W=X-Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent then, by the properties of characteristic functions

$$\phi_Z(u) = \phi_X(u)\phi_Y(u) = (\phi_X(u))^2$$

and

$$\phi_W(u) = \phi_X(u)\phi_Y(-u) = \phi_X(u)\phi_X(-u)$$

since $X$ and $Y$ are also identical.

So
$$(\phi_X(u))^3\phi_X(-u) = \phi_Z(u)\phi_W(u)$$

Can you take it from here?

**ADDENDUM** 
*(Now that the OP has found the way, I am completing this answer).*

Consider the random variable $S = Z+W = 2X$. Since $Z$ and $W$ are independent, then

$$\phi_S(u) = \phi_Z(u)\phi_W(u)$$
But also, since $S=2X$
$$\phi_S(u) = \phi_X(2u)$$

Linking equalities, we obtain

$$(\phi_X(u))^3\phi_X(-u) = \phi_X(2u)$$

Comment: Just did! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You're welcome.